# How to force reboot of Ubuntu phone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, reboot

To me at happened that Ubuntu phone went black, background light stayed on but it didn't react to any input. How can I force reboot just with the hardware keys alone?

Answer (score 2):

Pressing all three hardware buttons (volume up, volume down, lock) at the same time, for about 20 seconds, forces Ubuntu phone to reboot.

Comment: 10 seconds were not enough. 20 seconds is an approximation, could also just be 17. But quite long for sure!